# Error in Global.asax: 'RedirectPermanent' is not a member of 'System.Web.HttpResponse'

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, httpresponse

I'm trying to launch a legacy ASP.NET classic web solution in VS 2013 Community Edition locally for debugging. However, VS reports this error for Global.asax:

> 'RedirectPermanent' is not a member of 'System.Web.HttpResponse'

and points to this line of code:

```
Response.RedirectPermanent(host)
```

I definitely know that the RedirectPermanent method of the System.Web.HttpResponse object exists and works on a real web-server. And even more: my VS's IntelliSense displays the correct tooltip with the description of this method.

What it can be, and how to fix that?

---

An update: I found that changing the target framework from 4.5.1 to 4.0 helps to solve the problem, but why? HttpResponse.Redirect has not been removed from .NET 4.5.1, and it is still [there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirect(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case specifying the target Framework version in `web.config` explicitly helps to solve the problem:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
```